# why this.props in render() is undefined but has value in constructor()?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I encountered this weird behaviour that `this.props` in render() is undefined but has value in constructor(), anyone could help expplain why?

```
class Login extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){          
    super(props);     // props is an object 
  }


  render() {

    let {loginClick} = this.props // this.props is undefined

    let tpl = (<div className="login-box">

              </div>)
    return tpl
  }
}
```

the logged result:

```
{"page":{"status":"1"},"order":{}, function a(){}} // first result
{"page":{"status":"1", "b":{"a":"1"}},"order":{}, function a(){}} // second result
```

Comment: Drop `console.log(this.props)` in the first line in the `render` function and show us what does it log.

Comment: This is not the case. There's something else going on but testing that exact component in isolation never yields `this.props` as undefined. http://jsbin.com/suwiwigeta/edit?js,console,output - Tested on Chrome 59 (Latest build).

Comment: @Kinduser it gives the correct object, but why using debugger it give undefined?

Comment: Post the logged object into your question :)

Comment: @Kinduser i have updated the post, please check, thx!

Comment: There's no `loginClick` key in your props, so how do you want to use it? :)

Comment: How do you use this component?

Comment: @Kinduser there is, i kinda modified the logged result to make it look simpler. the problem is `this.props` the whole is shown as undefined with debugger, let along a single property of it.

Comment: What about `this.props.page`? What does it log?

Comment: @Kinduser it gives the same as above, the correct object.